# Using Raster Clip

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip, inverse-distance-weighted

I’m not super experienced in ArcMap, but I’m trying to clip an IDW to the outline of a grid of my study area in Mobile Bay (and the Mississippi Sound). Problem is that when I clip it, it looks weird.

Maybe the cell size is too big?

I can fix the problem with the inner contour lines, but the outline is pixelated and doesn’t match the outline of the grid I’m using for the clip.

[image]

I’ve attached a picture of the clip over the original IDW. Note the size of the cells of the clip vs the size in the IDW. The biggest problem is the outline, though. This is the grid I’m trying to clip to overlaid on the original IDW. Again, compare the outlines.

[image]

Comment: Update: I used the extract by mask tool instead of clipping and then went to the environments, changed cell size (under raster analysis) to “as specified below”, used the cell size 1, and used the grid as my mask. This made the outline exactly what I wanted, but the resolution within the boundary of the extract is still terrible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your comment of "the resolution within the boundary of the extract is still terrible" to mean that your IDW raster is too coarse. Try re-running your IDW with a cell size of 1, then use extract by mask with the environment settings you described (cell size=1, mask=grid polygon).  Also, if you are using Windows, the 'snipping tool' will be easier for sharing screenshots that taking photos.